# Why user.has_perm print always True?

Tags: python, django

A user is assigned to a student group and from the group remove delete_permission, but the below code returns true.

```
student_group  = Group.objects.get(name='student')

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Department)
department_permission = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
user = User.objects.get(email='test@gmail.com')
student_group.user_set.add(user)
for perm in department_permission:
    if perm.codename == "delete_department":
        student_group.permissions.remove(perm)
print(user.has_perm("quiz.delete_department"), "Quiz Permission after")
```

Comment: Is this a *superuser* (`is_admin` is `True`)?

Comment: This is not superuser(```is_admin``` is ```False```)

Comment: You didn't show the code that does the check, only how you call it.

Comment: Just at first sight what I understood is you are removing by checking with value `delete_department` but when you are checking in `has_perm` that time you are using `quiz.delete_department`. 

both shouldn't ve same ?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are cached on the user object see [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching). Also `refresh_from_db()` won't work you need to fetch the user again see [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26514).

In your case:

```
student_group  = Group.objects.get(name='student')

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Department)
department_permission = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
user = User.objects.get(email='test@gmail.com')
student_group.user_set.add(user)
for perm in department_permission:
    if perm.codename == "delete_department":
        student_group.permissions.remove(perm)

# re-fetch the user from the database after permission change
user = User.objects.get(email='test@gmail.com')

print(user.has_perm("quiz.delete_department"), "Quiz Permission after")
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: please check the edit I made